# Cant add / see Activity post getting Warning : Division by zero - Buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, warnings, buddypress

Hi i am using BUDDYPRESS with wordpress 3.9.1 ..

Getting Below warring message.. i cant add post and cant see also …

Warning: Division by zero in `/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-activity/bp-activity-template.php` on `line 783`

Line No 783 : is

```
if ( ! empty( $activities_template->pag_page ) ) {
$remaining_pages = floor( ( $activities_template->total_activity_count – 1 ) / ( $activities_template->pag_num * $activities_template->pag_page ) );
}
```

Full function of above :

> ```
>  /**
> * Return true when there are more activity items to be shown than currently appear.
> *
> * @since BuddyPress (1.5)
> *
> * @global object $activities_template {@link BP_Activity_Template}
> * @uses apply_filters() To call the ‘bp_activity_has_more_items’ hook.
> *
> * @return bool $has_more_items True if more items, false if not.
> */
> function bp_activity_has_more_items() {
> global $activities_template;
>
> $remaining_pages = 0;
>
> if ( ! empty( $activities_template->pag_page ) ) {
> $remaining_pages = floor( ( $activities_template->total_activity_count – 1 ) / (
> $activities_template->pag_num * $activities_template->pag_page ) );
> }
>
> $has_more_items = (int) $remaining_pages ? true : false;
>
> return apply_filters( 'bp_activity_has_more_items', $has_more_items );
> }
> ```

I cant add / see my Post … there is Load More link but when click it nothing happen .

domain.com/dashboard and domain.com/member/username

above both page does not works

ALSO what i noted is … when i am login With Admin account then i can see and post activity.

But as a new user register ( Subscriber ) on website ..he cant add nor see his activity ( post ) … but his activity can be added and seen by admin of website

below are the version i am using

```
WordPress : 3.9.1
BuddyPress : Version 2.0.1
BuddyPress Activity Comment Notifier : Version 1.0.8
BuddyPress Activity Plus : Version 1.6
BuddyPress Friends Only Activity Stream : Version 1.0
```

Comment: to fix your error simple don't divide by zero values, check if equal to zero first ``if(($activities_template->pag_num * $activities_template->pag_page) == 0) $remaining_pages = 0;``

Comment: thanks for reply ...hey can you pls provide me full code ? pls

Answer (score 1):

to fix your error simple don't divide by zero values, check first if any variable is `0`

```
function bp_activity_has_more_items() {
    global $activities_template;

    $remaining_pages = 0;

    if ( ! empty( $activities_template->pag_page ) ) {
        if( ($activities_template->pag_num * $activities_template->pag_page) == 0 )
        {
            $remaining_pages = 0;
        } else {
            $remaining_pages = floor( ( $activities_template->total_activity_count-1 ) / ($activities_template->pag_num * $activities_template->pag_page ) );
        }
    }

    $has_more_items = (int) $remaining_pages ? true : false;

    return apply_filters('bp_activity_has_more_items', $has_more_items );
}
```

Comment: hey thanks ... but replacing your code .. i am getting below error :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /buddypress/bp-activity/bp-activity-template.php on line 788

Comment: and line is :            $remaining_pages = floor( ( $activities_template->total_activity_count – 1 ) / ($activities_template->pag_num * $activities_template->pag_page ) );

Comment: please check your code i use ``'`` while you use ``‘`` for ``bp_activity_has_more_items`` in your question

Comment: thanks for reply ... actually code is 'bp_activity_has_more_items'  this only but i am getting error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /buddypress/bp-activity/bp-activity-template.php on line 788    which is   $remaining_pages = floor( ( $activities_template->total_activity_count – 1 ) / ($activities_template->pag_num * $activities_template->pag_page ) )

Comment: i have corrected " return apply_filters( 'bp_activity_has_more_items', $has_more_items ); "

Comment: Hey i did : function bp_activity_has_more_items() {
 global $activities_template;

 $remaining_pages = 0;
 

 if ( ! empty( $activities_template->pag_page ) ) {
        if( ($activities_template->pag_num * $activities_template->pag_page) == 0 ) {
            $remaining_pages = 0;
        } else {
  $remaining_pages = floor( ( $activities_template->total_activity_count - 1 ) / ( $activities_template->pag_num * $activities_template->pag_page ) );
        }
    }


 $has_more_items  = (int) $remaining_pages ? true : false;

 return apply_filters( 'bp_activity_has_more_items', $has_more_items );
}

Comment: and error is gone now ... but listing is not seen ... as said above admin user can see but other users cant see there list ...but error is gone now..any idea ?

Comment: got the solution : solved my self :

its was because of  BuddyPress Friends Only Activity Stream : Version 1.0 PLUGIN